# Search query on JSON column in postgresql

Tags: php, sql, postgresql

I have a column 'tags' in my table 'categories', which is a json type

```
----------------------------------------------------------------
id    name                tags
----------------------------------------------------------------
1     Electronics         ["phones","computers","watches"]
2     Fashion             ["jewelry","costumes","watches"]
3     Food                ["cakes","sweets","juices"]
4     Tools               ["keyboards","pens","drills"]
----------------------------------------------------------------
```

I want to fetch all categories that are having any one of the tags in the array that I match in my SQL

```
select * from categories where tags::jsonb ?| '{"watches","sweets"}'
```

I expect the result set as

```
------------------------------
1     Electronics 
2     Fashion
3     Food  
------------------------------
```

so first two categories matches for "watches" and third category for "sweets"

the above query perfectly worked on my local server as thats on 9.4
but when I moved to live itis 9.2.15 there and having no jsonb, returning error, is there a similar operator for json type that returns any one of the matching elements in query?

Comment: with no jsonb support you can try `where tags::text like '%watches%' OR  tags::text like '% sweets%'`, but of course better using 9.5

Comment: looks like 9.2 is only available on cpanel (or on my server), Im using a cloud VPS and the latest available there is 9.2, and looks like no jsob support on that

Comment: I would suggest you to use the ltree type (provided by the LTree extension) instead of JSON for this use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found a simple solution for this problem

I turned the json type to text first
then replaced my search expression with `SIMILAR TO`

here is the example sql

```
select * from categories where tags SIMILAR TO  ("watches"|"sweets")
```

" are must because they help in fetching apt matches, like when you have tags like `watches`, `watches-new` using SIMILAR to with out " like `(watches|sweets)` will result both, if you use with "" on a json stored on text column, it works just as you wanted it to.

hope this helps some one like me.

Comment: This will match also portions of words and phrases. Using `tags ~ '\m(watches|sweets)\M'` would render results without portions of words, but would also find words that are part of phrases.

Answer (score 0):

is the column `categories.tags` json or text datatype? JSON datatype support is very limited in PostgreSQL 9.2, so although you may store JSON data in it, you'll have trouble processing it in any way other than casting to text.

You could use the array overlap `&&`, instead of the jsonb `?|` operator:

```
with
  categories(id,name,tags) as (
    values (1, 'Electronics', '["phones","computers","watches"]'::json),
           (2, 'Fashion', '["jewelry","costumes","watches"]'),
           (3, 'Food', '["cakes","sweets","juices"]'),
           (4, 'Tools', '["keyboards","pens","drills"]'))

select *
from categories
where regexp_replace(regexp_replace(tags::text, '^\[', '{'), '\]$', '}')::text[] && '{watches,sweets}'::text[]
```

Comment: tried this- but error " ERROR: operator does not exist: text &&"

Comment: @heingcoler You may be missing a typecast `text[]` somewhere (since the error is giving you `text &&` and in the example both sides of the `&&` operator are `text[]`)

Comment: thanks, and again error with this "Query failed: ERROR: missing dimension value" looks like some thing is expecting inside those [], or do you know any other way of searching on text column?

Comment: @heingcoler How similar is your data to the samples in your question? Are you using the exact same code with both regexp_replace on your tags field? Perhaps you can select *, regexp_replace(...)::text[] from categories limit x, specifying a small number for x to test, and then increasing it until you find the row that's causing the problem.

Comment: just posted a solution that I worked for this problem, please have a look if possible, any suggestions/improvements are happily accepted.